# multiple HTML in Phonegap applications

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

Can we have multiple HTML files in Phonegap application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's an example from their git repo: 
http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/blob/master/PhoneGapTutorial/www/index.html

```
  <a href="geolocation.html">
    <div class="item">
      <h2>GeoLocation</h2>
     </div>
  </a>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I am facing same problem, but I need to add different html files into one file, I have used jquery ajax calls but it will always try to download it from server, but i want to use www folder. I cannot anchor these files as mentioned above, I want to populate that html in some dynamic div created at runtime of main html page in phonegap??please help

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. Just link to it from your html (anchor tag), and the html file should be in your www folder. Don't forget to add "phonegap.js" in a script tag like your index.html file if you want to access Phonegap functions.